# Bootstrap top-fixed navigation bar with logo left-indent and login and register button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a bootstrap naivgation bar that is fixed top, and contains a register and login button closer to the right end of the bar. What are some of the best practices for this? The bootstrap documentation does not seem to help much. The bar must not be collapsible.

**EDIT**

This is the updated version of your code. Is this an appropriate way to use bootstrap though?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App Name</a>
        </div><!--end navbar header-->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div><!--end container-->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bootstrap example providing what you want: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron.

You can easily add another button:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        <!-- BUTTON ADDED -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```